# Potential leak problem when taking control of setter method of retained object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, retain

So here is my code:

```
-(void)setMovie:(NSURL *)movieLocal {
    movie = movieLocal;
    [self.movie retain];
 ...
}
```

And i get this error:

> Potential leak of an object allocated on line 43

Line 43 is `[self.movie retain];`. Am i doing something wrong, and how can i get rid of this error?

Comment: try self.movie = movieLocal; and remove [self.movie retain]; statement.

Comment: It's a setter method. If i do self.movie, that's just calling the same setter method in a never ending loop.

Comment: Never use self when initializing/retaining, only for autorelease objects

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues here:

- The old value for `movie` is never released
- 'movie' and 'movieLocal' might point to the exact same object. If that is the case, you will call retain on movie/movieLocal without a subsequent balanced release call.

You might want to use the following:

```
-(void)setMovie:(NSURL *)movieLocal {
    if (movie == movieLocal) {
        return;
    }
    [movie release];
    movie = [movieLocal retain];
    //...
}
```

Comment: Don't you think if movie would be nil then it will create problem?

Comment: Where would movie being nil cause a problem? You can send a message to nil without issue.

Comment: In that case, maybe it should be `if (movie == nil) [movie release];`. I'm surprised there isn't a standard way of overriding a retained setter, with that code available online.

Comment: The problem of `movie` and `movieLocal` being the same object is that if you are the only owner of the object and you release its retain count drops to 0 and its immediately deallocated without a chance of being retained by the following statement.

Comment: So what does the `return;` line do? I don't understand that part.

Comment: @Andrew I am still not clear on why you need to check whether movie is nil or not? If it is nil, then the call does nothing. If it is no nil then we will be releasing the old version of movie we are no longer interested in and subsequently retain the new value we care about. If they are the same object, we never reach this code.

Comment: @Andrew `return;` exits the function. We are setting movie to the current value of move, so we do not need to retain or release it.

Comment: It's not necessary or even useful to test for nil. Sending any message to nil is a no-op.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the proper setter:

```
-(void)setMovie:(NSURL *)movieLocal {
    if (movie != movieLocal) {
        [movie release]; 
        movie = movieLocal;
        [movie retain];
    }
}
```

However, if you declared your property (in .h file):

```
@propert (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *movie;
```

and synthesized it in .m file, by `@synthesize movie;`, than there is no need to explicitly override the setter - the code above will be generated automatically for you. So whenever you want to set your `movie` you'll just call `self.movie = newMovie;` which will be equivalent to calling `[self setMovie:newMovie];`.

For more info read a section "Declared Properties" in [Learning Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html) guide.

EDIT: to explain what was wrong with your setter.

```
-(void)setMovie:(NSURL *)movieLocal {
    movie = movieLocal;     // first line
    [self.movie retain];    // second line
    ...
}
```

In 1st line you are assigning `movie` to point to `movieLocal`, but you don't release old `NSURL` object that `movie` was pointing to before assignment. This was way, your causing a memory leak - you abandon memory, so it can never be relinquished back by your app. In general, abandoning memory is an easy way to get you application terminated by iOS, when objects are big and often leaked.

In 2nd line you are calling you `setMovie` setter again as `self.movie =` syntax causes the runtime to call a setter for `movie` property. This time it'll cause an infinite loop.

I hope my wording was clear for you and my answer helpful.

Comment: Your setter is correct and so is paulfi's. The two are equivalent. you can shorten the two last lines into one: `movie = [movieLocal retain];`